# Calculating orbital movements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am working on a way to display a simplified orbital system (no simulation of forces, circular paths only) in vanilla Javascript.

I have so far managed to make it work as long as the orbits are around a fixed point (ex: earth around the sun)

When I try to represent objects orbiting around other objects who are themselves in orbit (ex: moon around the earth) then the path goes all over the place.

It seems to work when the radius is 1 but not farther.

Any ideas ?

```js
//OBJECTS
let world = {
  size: 0,
  map: [],
  objects: [],
  init: function(size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.map = Array.from(Array(this.size), () => new Array(this.size));
  },
  update: function() {
    this.map = Array.from(Array(this.size), () => new Array(this.size));
    this.objects.forEach(e => {
      this.map[e.y][e.x] = e.logo;
    });
  }
}

//CLASSES
class CelestialObject {
  constructor(logo, x, y, orbitalparent, orbitalradius) {
    this.logo = ` ${logo} `;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.orbit = {
      parent: orbitalparent,
      radius: orbitalradius,
      path: [],
      current: 0,
    }

    world.objects.push(this);
  }

  setOrbit() {
    if (this.orbit.parent != null) {
      let x0 = this.orbit.parent.x;
      let y0 = this.orbit.parent.y;
      let x = this.orbit.radius;
      let y = 0;
      let radiusError = 1 - x;
      let points = [];

      while (x >= y) {
        points.push([x + x0, y + y0]);
        points.push([y + x0, x + y0]);
        points.push([-x + x0, y + y0]);
        points.push([-y + x0, x + y0]);
        points.push([-x + x0, -y + y0]);
        points.push([-y + x0, -x + y0]);
        points.push([x + x0, -y + y0]);
        points.push([y + x0, -x + y0]);
        y++;

        if (radiusError < 0) radiusError += 2 * y + 1;
        else {
          x--;
          radiusError += 2 * (y - x + 1);
        }
      }

      //remove duplicates
      for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < points.length;) {
          if (points[i][0] == points[j][0] && points[i][1] == points[j][1]) points.splice(j, 1);
          else j++;
        }
      }

      //sort clockwise
      points.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y);
      points.sort((a, b) => b.x - a.x);
      const center = {
        x: x0,
        y: y0
      };
      let startAng;
      points.forEach(point => {
        let ang = Math.atan2(point[0] - center.y, point[1] - center.x);
        if (!startAng) startAng = ang;
        else if (ang < startAng) ang += Math.PI * 2;
        point.angle = ang;
      });
      points.sort((a, b) => a.angle - b.angle);

      //set new position
      this.x = points[this.orbit.current][0];
      this.y = points[this.orbit.current][1];
      if (this.orbit.current < points.length - 1) this.orbit.current++;
      else this.orbit.current = 0;
    }
  }
}

//FUNCTIONS
function draw() {
  let map = document.getElementById('map');

  map.innerHTML = '';
  world.update();

  for (let i = 0; i < world.size; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < world.size; j++) {
      if (world.map[j][i] != undefined) map.innerHTML += world.map[j][i];
      else map.innerHTML += ' . ';
    }
    map.innerHTML += '</br>';
  }
}

//RUNTIME
world.init(15);

let sun = new CelestialObject('s', 7, 7, null, null);
let earth = new CelestialObject('e', 0, 0, sun, 4);
let moon = new CelestialObject('m', 0, 0, earth, 2);

setInterval(() => {
  world.objects.forEach(e => {
    e.setOrbit();
  });
  draw();
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Tad's Basic Game Objects to make it quick and easy to play with the values. After an initial start up the circles find their path and stick with it. It seems that speed is the major factor, the moon needs to be able to catch up to the earth and circle past it.

```js
(function() {

  var outerSpace = [ //16x16 grid   5x16 = 80
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
    [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
  ];//MapTravelers would default collide with any non [0,0] spots in their map.

  var earth = new tabageos.MapTraveler(20,20,6,6,outerSpace);//x,y,width,height,map
  earth.circleDistance = 32;earth._veloc.x = 4;earth._veloc.y = 2;
  earth.maxForce = 64;earth.maxSpeed = 4;

  var moon = new tabageos.MapTraveler(4,4,2,2,outerSpace);
  moon.circleDistance = 6;moon._veloc.x = 2;moon._veloc.y = 1;
  moon.maxForce = 64;moon.maxSpeed = 4;

  //different maxSpeeds reproduce the problem you stated.
  //seems speed needs to be the same for the earth and moon to look right.

  var sun = new tabageos.MapTraveler(40,40,12,12,outerSpace);

  var display = new tabageos.CanvasObject(document.getElementById("display"),80,80);

  function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  
    display.clear();
  
    moon.circle(earth._pos);//change velocity and force to circle
    earth.circle(sun._pos);
 
    earth.update(0,0,1);//based on velocity and force
    moon.update(0,0,1);//update _pos and x and y with no collision of map
  
    display.drawCircle(earth.x, earth.y, 6, "#A52A2A");//position, radius, color
    display.drawCircle(moon.x, moon.y, 2, "#c8c8c8");
    display.drawCircle(sun.x, sun.y, 12, "#ffff00");
  
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/tabageos/tabageos/tbgs_min.js"></script>
<canvas style="width:80px;height:80px" id="display"></canvas>
```

What I'm referring to as 'force' is really just another point,
two points are utilized with trigonometry to make the circling happen,
a point representing velocity and another to shift the velocity called forceApplier. Here are the main functionalities making it all happen,
so you can see everything from scratch.

```
circle = function(mp) {
    
    var l = Math.sqrt((this._pos.x - mp.x) * (this._pos.x - mp.x) + (this._pos.y - mp.y) * (this._pos.y - mp.y));
    var thex = (this._pos.x - mp.x) / l;
    var they = (this._pos.y - mp.y) / l;
    var destx = mp.x + (thex*this.circleDistance) - this._pos.x + this._veloc.x;
    var desty = mp.y + (they*this.circleDistance) - this._pos.y + this._veloc.y;
    this.forceApplier.x = destx;
    this.forceApplier.y = desty;
    this.forceApplier._length = 0;
    this.forceApplier._angle = 0;
    
};



update = function() {

    this.forceApplier.truncate(this.maxForce);
        this.forceApplier.divide(this.mass, 0);
        this._veloc.add(this.forceApplier.multiply(this._deltaTime,0), 0);
        this.forceApplier.reset();
        this._veloc._length = 0;
        this._veloc._angle = 0;
        this._veloc.truncate(this.maxSpeed);
    
    this._pos.addBy(this._veloc.x * this._deltaTime, this._veloc.y * this._deltaTime, 0);

};
```

maxForce, mas, maxSpeed are just numbers set to whatever desired values.
deltaTime is 1000 divided by the desired frame rate.
The way your doing it seems to be more involved than it needs to be.
You can simply utilize points and trig.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I am looking for an answer for vanilla Javascript, also I do not want to simulate forces or be accurate on the physics, I would like this to be a simplified display that shows circular orbits. I have edited my question to make these points clearer. Thanks again

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the inner workings of the circle and update methods.
It's all done with points, no real forces.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to detail this, I will try to implement it this way